# angular filter with ng-click + input

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

how can I get a filter with ng-click out of an ul as second filter for an ngtable?

```
<ul class="artGroups">
  <li class="" ng-repeat="artGroup in artGroups">
    <a href="#" ng-click="">{{artGroup.artGroupName}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Amdx2BzEWQWVYmRAgTMw

Comment: what are you trying to filter out on `ng-click()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a function on the main controller to change a value when an `artGroup` is selected:

```
$scope.selectedGroup = '';
$scope.setGroup = function(group) {
    $scope.selectedGroup = group;
}
```

And wire up the `ng-click` directive:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="setGroup(artGroup.artGroupId)">{{artGroup.artGroupName}}</a>
```

Then you can set up another custom filter on the `tr`, using that `selectedGroup` variable on the scope:

```
<tr ng-repeat="article in articles | filter:searchText | isArtGroup:selectedGroup">
```

Then create the custom filter to filter the articles based on whether or not they fall into that `artGroupId`:

```
app.filter('isArtGroup', function(){
  return function(values, groupId) {
    if(!groupId) {
      // initially don't filter
      return values;
    }
    // filter when we have a selected groupId
    return values.filter(function(value){
      return value.artGroupId === groupId;
    })
  }
})
```

Here's all of that working together in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UZsjiyt4BVJlt1BKzUDZ?p=preview)

Comment: In the `setGroup` function you can just check to see if the groupId is set to the current value, if not set it to an empty string